# mysql union all when creating views

Tags: mysql

I have the following code, if i run the code as an sql script it works but if i want to create a view from it i got this error: 1166 - Incorrect Column Name ''

```
select `c`.`package_id` AS `package_id`,
`c`.`student_id` AS `student_id`,
`bs`.`name` AS `stud_name`,
`c`.`payed_date` AS `payed_date`,
(case `c`.`type` when 'e' then 'Vizsgadíj' when 'c' then 'Tanfolyam díj' else '' end) AS `name`,
`c`.`course_price` AS `price`,
`c`.`pay_form` AS `pay_form`,
`c`.`venue_id` AS `venue_id` 
from (`bma_student_pays` `c` 
join `bma_students` `bs` on((`bs`.`id` = `c`.`student_id`)))

union all 

select '0' AS `0`,'0' AS `0`,'' AS ``,`e`.`making_date` AS `making_date`,`e`.`name` AS `name`,`e`.`price` AS `price`,`e`.`type` AS `type`,`e`.`venue_id` AS `venue_id` 
from `bma_extra_makings` `e`

union all 

select '','','',i.inv_due,i.inv_name,i.inv_amount,i.`mode`,i.venue_id 
from bma_invoices i 
where i.inv_type='K'
```

Any help would really good.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your second query (first UNION ALL), you have as your third column:

```
'' AS ``
```

This is not valid - remove the AS clause and all should be well.

Comment: Further, all columns are aliased in the first query. It isn't necessary (and may be incorrect) to alias columns in the unioned queries *differently* from those in the first query. The OP can just leave the aliases off of the second query entirely.

Comment: @DanJ: Absolutely, but that wouldn't break the view creation.

Comment: Ah, right; it doesn't care what the columns in the second query are called, just that there are the same number and type of them. My comment was more of an FYI. :)